# UITextView lineSpacing causes different cursor height inbetween paragraph lines

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm using `NSMutableParagraphStyle` in my `UITextview` for adding linespace between each row text.

When I type something in textview, cursor height is normal. but when I move cursor position to text on the 2nd row (not the last row), cursor height is getting bigger.

[image: big caret]

What should I do to make cursor height normal in every row of the texts?
 This is code I'm currently using:

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 30.;
textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16];
textView.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"My Text" attributes:@{NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle}];
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Finally I found a solution that solve my problem.

Changing the cursor height is possible by subclassing the `UITextView`, then overriding the `caretRectForPosition:position` function. For example:

```
- (CGRect)caretRectForPosition:(UITextPosition *)position {
    CGRect originalRect = [super caretRectForPosition:position];
    originalRect.size.height = 18.0;
    return originalRect;
}
```

Documentation link: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinput/1614518-caretrectforposition

---

### Update: Swift 2.x or Swift 3.x

See [Nate's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34537839/1467988).

---

### Update: Swift 4.x or Swift 5.x

For Swift 4.x use `caretRect(for position: UITextPosition) -> CGRect`.

```
import UIKit

class MyTextView: UITextView {

    override func caretRect(for position: UITextPosition) -> CGRect {
        var superRect = super.caretRect(for: position)
        guard let font = self.font else { return superRect }

        // "descender" is expressed as a negative value, 
        // so to add its height you must subtract its value
        superRect.size.height = font.pointSize - font.descender 
        return superRect
    }
}
```

Documentation link: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinput/1614518-caretrect

Comment: Is this a documented method? (EDIT: Yes, it's in the `UITextInput` protocol which `UITextView` conforms to (https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInput_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextInput).

Comment: When selecting this text the handles are really Big, any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 11):

And for Swift 2.*x* or Swift 3.*x*:

```
import UIKit

class MyTextView : UITextView {
    override func caretRectForPosition(position: UITextPosition) -> CGRect {
        var superRect = super.caretRectForPosition(position)
        guard let isFont = self.font else { return superRect }

        superRect.size.height = isFont.pointSize - isFont.descender 
            // "descender" is expressed as a negative value, 
            // so to add its height you must subtract its value

        return superRect
    }
}
```

Comment: Swift 4 changes `caretRectForPosition(position: UITextPosition)` to: `caretRect(for position: UITextPosition)`