# How can I prevent a UITextView from drawing a long caret when I've specified a large paragraph spacing in iOS?

Tags: ios, uikit, uitextview, caret, nsparagraphstyle

I'm setting paragraph style like so:

```
NSTextStorage *textStorage = self.textView.textStorage;
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
paragraphStyle.paragraphSpacing = FBTweakValue(@"Authoring View", @"Paragraph Style", @"Paragraph Spacing", 40.f);

[textStorage setAttributes:@{NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle} range:[textStorage fullRange]];
```

[image: screenie]

EDIT: I found a partial answer below — it fixes the single line caret fine. However, when you drag out the selection range over a number of words, you get this:

[image]

Back to square one! How can you specify the height of the caret then?

**NB:** My question was posted [once before on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24288819/how-do-i-stop-textkit-drawing-a-long-caret-filling-paragraph-spacing-with-para), but it was unceremoniously deleted. If you're going to do that, please at least give me a reason. Thanks SO.

Comment: Actually, even that doesn't fully resolve the issue. When using a range selection (dragging the selection across some words), the two 'poles' of the selection are still long!

Comment: Then say that in your answer on this question. Then ping me so I can retract my close vote :)

Comment: Heya @SantaClaus I've made the edits you were probably looking for.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Okay, I found an answer under slightly different wording — check out
[iOS - UITextView lineSpacing make cursor height not same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20207961/ios-uitextview-linespacing-make-cursor-height-not-same/20311650#20311650)</s>

EDIT: I found that the possible duplicate question + solution is only a partial solution as it doesn't fix the caret if you select a range of characters.