# How do you get correct caret size AND position when using NSMutableParagraphStyle and paragraphSpacingBefore in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring, caret, nsmutableattributedstring

I've been playing around with attributed text in a UITextView (Swift 4.2 and noticed that once I introduced "paragraphSpacingBefore" into my design, the Caret becmae too large on the first line of each new paragraph.

I found this suggested fix on Stackoverflow which seemed to work ok to fix the caret size. The problem I found was the caret itself floats above the target line when that line was the start of a new paragraph.

[UITextView lineSpacing make cursor height not same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20207961/uitextview-linespacing-make-cursor-height-not-same)

[Caret Floats above the target line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWWLZ.png)

I tried solving it, maintaining the core idea of the original solution and adding some offset logic. During debugging I noticed that the original answer for caret size always adjusts the size even when not required so I added a variance filter (only adjust if variance > 10%). Did this because I think adjusting every time will interfere with my soln. to the floating caret problem.

If someone can take a look at my proposed approach, suggest improvements or a better way etc i'd be grateful:

```
override func caretRect(for position: UITextPosition) -> CGRect {
    var superRect = super.caretRect(for: position)
    guard let isFont = self.font else {
        return superRect
    }
    let proposedHeight: CGFloat = isFont.pointSize - isFont.descender
    var delta: CGFloat = superRect.size.height - proposedHeight
    delta = (delta * delta).squareRoot()

    //If the delta is < 10% of the original height just return the original rect
    if delta / superRect.size.height < 0.1 {
        return superRect
    }

    superRect.size.height = isFont.pointSize - isFont.descender
    // "descender" is expressed as a negative value,
    // so to add its height you must subtract its value
    superRect.origin.y = superRect.origin.y + delta
    // delta is used to correct for resized caret floating above the target line

    return superRect
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution:

```
// Fix long cursor height when at the end of paragraph with paragraphspacing and wrong cursor position in titles with paragraph spacing before
override public func caretRect(for position: UITextPosition) -> CGRect {
    var superRect = super.caretRect(for: position)
    guard let isFont = self.font else { return superRect }

    let location = self.offset(from: self.beginningOfDocument, to: position)
    if let paragrahStyle = self.storage.attribute(.paragraphStyle, at: location, effectiveRange: nil) as? NSParagraphStyle {
        superRect.origin.y += paragrahStyle.paragraphSpacingBefore
    }

    superRect.size.height = isFont.pointSize - isFont.descender
    return superRect
}
```

The real problem `paragraphSpacingBefore`. So all you have to do is to get the paragraph styling attributes, get the spacing and move the cursor by that spacing. This works well with all the text.