# UITextView add new line but not new paragrafh

Tags: swift, uikit, uitextview, text-editor, nsparagraphstyle

in a UItextView I am using paragraphStyle to space the new paragraphs between them.

```
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.paragraphSpacing = 20
```

However, I would need to insert a new line without it being a new paragraph.
Here is an example

```
Test first line.
Test new line.

Test new paragraph
```

I tried to use `\r` or to assign `paragraphSpacing = 0` to the new line but it always distances it.
How could I go about inserting a new line without inserting a new paragraph? It's possible to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `paragraphStyle.spacing = 0` for first line then `paragraphStyle.spacing = 20` and `paragraphStyle.spacing = 0` for the third line. So basically spacing changes the space after the line it was set for not before.

```
    let line1 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Test first line\n")
    
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.spacing = 0
    attrStr.setAttributes([.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle,
                           .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .regular),
                           .foregroundColor: UIColor.black],
                          range: NSMakeRange(0, line1))
    
    let line2 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Test new line.\n")
    let paragraphStyle2 = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle2.lineSpacing = 20
    line2.setAttributes([.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle2,
                         .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .regular),
                         .foregroundColor: UIColor.black],
                          range: NSMakeRange(0, line2.string.count))
    
    let line3 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Test new paragraph")
    let paragraphStyle3 = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle3.spacing = 0
    line3.setAttributes([.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle3,
                         .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .regular),
                         .foregroundColor: UIColor.black],
                          range: NSMakeRange(0, line3.string.count))
    
    line1.append(line2)
    line1.append(line3)
    
    textView.attributedText = line1
```

Comment: for different cursor height https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20207961/uitextview-linespacing-causes-different-cursor-height-inbetween-paragraph-lines